# Change Overflow Menu Style?

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to change the color of the overflow icon, menu background color, and text color. The Text color is changing, and I added a new icon but it is bigger than the original and the original is still there. How do I fix the overflow button and change the background color? Thanks in advance.

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>

<item name="android:actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.Overflow</item>
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Overflow</item>
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" >@style/AppTheme.TextAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" >@style/AppTheme.TextAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/window_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearanceLargePopupMenu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text</item>
</style>
</resources>
```